# What are the supported extensions for the AMD Ryzen 7 3700X?

Tags: amd-ryzen

The [AMD Ryzen Threadripper PRO 7995WX](https://www.amd.com/en/product/13841) lists the
supported extensions as: `AES, AMD-V, AVX, AVX2, AVX512, FMA3, MMX(+), SHA, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, SSE4A, SSSE3, x86-64`. Looking at [AMD Ryzen 7 3700X](https://www.amd.com/en/product/8446) I don't see any extensions listed. What extensions does the AMD Ryzen 7 3700X support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Wikichip](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2) the Ryzen 7 3700X is based on the Zen 2 core, which supports the following extensions:

> MOVBE, MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4A, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, POPCNT,
> AVX, AVX2, AES, PCLMUL, FSGSBASE, RDRND, FMA3, F16C, BMI, BMI2,
> RDSEED, ADCX, PREFETCHW, CLFLUSHOPT, XSAVE, SHA, UMIP, CLZERO